# Expansion of the $S$-operator and Normal Ordering

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, renormalization

To phrase my question I will use the example, which we used as an exercise in my introducory QFT lecture. We considered a theory of a real scalar field $\Phi$ and a complex scalar field $\phi$. The Lagrangian of the theory was given as
$$
\mathcal L = \frac 1 2\partial_\mu \Phi\partial^\mu\Phi - \frac 1 2M^2\Phi^2 + (\partial_\mu \phi^\dagger)(\partial^\mu \phi) - m^2 \phi^\dagger\phi + \lambda\phi^\dagger\phi\Phi .
$$
So now we had to expand the $S$-operator up to quadratic order in the coupling $\lambda$. Hence I calculated the following
$$
\begin{align}
S &= T\left\{\exp\left(i\int \text d^4x\ \ \mathbf{: }\,\lambda\phi^\dagger\phi\Phi\,\mathbf{:}\right)\right\}\\
&= \mathbf 1 + i\lambda \int\text d^4x\ \ T\left\{\mathbf{:}\phi^\dagger(x)\phi(x)\Phi(x)\mathbf{:}\right\} \\ & \phantom{=1i}+ \frac{(i\lambda)^2}{2}\int\int\text d^4x_1 \text d^4x_2 T\left\{\mathbf{:}\phi^\dagger(x_1)\phi(x_1)\Phi(x_1)\mathbf{:}\ \mathbf{:}\phi^\dagger(x_2)\phi(x_2)\Phi(x_2)\mathbf{:}\right\} + \mathcal O(\lambda^3),\quad(1)
\end{align}
$$
where $T\{\circ\}$ denotes the time ordering of operators and $\mathbf{:}\circ\mathbf{:}$ denotes the normal ordering of operators.
This expression I further "simplified" using Wicks Theorem. But in the solution to the exercise there was no normal ordering right at the start, so the solution wrote
$$
\begin{align}
S &= T\left\{\exp\left(i\int \text d^4x\ \lambda\phi^\dagger\phi\Phi\right)\right\}\\
&= \mathbf 1 + i\lambda \int\text d^4x\ \ T\left\{\phi^\dagger(x)\phi(x)\Phi(x)\right\} \\ & \phantom{=1i}+ \frac{(i\lambda)^2}{2}\int\int\text d^4x_1 \text d^4x_2 T\left\{\phi^\dagger(x_1)\phi(x_1)\Phi(x_1)\phi^\dagger(x_2)\phi(x_2)\Phi(x_2)\right\} + \mathcal O(\lambda^3),\quad (2)
\end{align}
$$
and then applied Wicks theorem. So one can see that these two approaches do not lead to the same answer, since by applying Wicks theorem on approach $(1)$ you won't get any contraction between fields evaluated at the same point in space-time (for terms quadratic in the coupling). Whereas in approach $(2)$ you will get contractions between fields evaluated at the same point in space-time.

So to my understanding we need the normal ordering of the field operators to make "sense" out of products of "distribution-valued" operators. Therefore I used approach (1), since I thought that equation (2) would be even less sensible.

But the tutor said that if we would not normal order in the first place the terms we would get additionally would cancel with their counter terms in renormalization. So actually I am pretty confused,
is eq. (1) or eq. (2) right or both? And if both are "correct" depending on how the result is treated in further calculations could someone shed some light on why eq. (2) makes any sense in the first place (since I thought we need normal ordering due to the
distributional nature of the field operators)?

**Edit:**
As discussed in the comments this might boil down to the fact that the quantization procedure itself does not contain the "need" or rather require normal ordering, but we need to make sense of the whole calculation and it does not matter when to do so. (Which is actually not really satisfying)

Comment: @Jakob No, I have no problem applying Wicks Theorem. The Problem is even before we apply Wicks theorem. Is the interaction Lagrangian always normal ordered, and if not why?

Comment: I know, but I am fully aware of this fact, actually this leads to the problem I am having, which I adress in:
"So one can see that these two approaches do not lead to the same answer, since using Wicks theorem on approach (1) you won't get any contraction between fields evaluated at the same point in space-time (for terms quadratic in the coupling). Whereas in approach (2) you will get contractions between fields evaluated at the same point in space-time."

Comment: Okay, I see. Could you provide a reference for equation (1)? Or better, the definition of the S-matrix in the first line.

Comment: Actually I cannot. The "derivation" which my professor gave is not found neither in the textbook by Schwartz nor in the textbook by Peskin and Schröder. Actually I am really annoyed by the non consitency of the introductory QFT literature. If you relly want it I can copy most parts of the derivation in the script of my professor, but that would take a while.

Comment: The contraction of two fields taken at the same point is divergent. These divergent terms can be eliminated in calculations by the appropriate counterterms. So which approach you use, makes no difference in the end. I believe that is what your tutor may mean.

Comment: This is what I think my tutor meant, but how does a not normal ordered Lagrangian/Hamitonian makes sense in the first place?

Comment: The two Lagrangians eventually give the same results. Why would one of them not make sense?

Comment: Well then it might be a matter of taste, but I understand the quantization procedure the following way: We start by a classical theory (In this case a classical field theory). In this classical theory the objects in the Lagrangian are field configurations $\phi : \mathcal M \to \mathcal S$ where $\mathcal M$ is spacetime and $\mathcal S$ is some target space. These field configurations commute in the classical field theory, hence when quatizing the theory we must choose an arrangement of the field operators, since it s not dictated by the classical theory. The only sensible way to arrange ...

Comment: ... the operators is given by the normal ordered product of the field operators since otherwise vacuum expectation values will diverge. So a not normal ordered Hamiltonian/Lagrangian makes no sense.

Comment: Formally you are entirely correct. Pragmatically this is not important. Realistically maybe your tutor was just being careless by not using NO but didn’t want to admit it and found a way out - or just wanted you to think about it…

Comment: Have a look at [this physics se thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/591070/normal-ordering-of-hamiltonian) and the comments and references therein. I think this is exactly your question, but does not contain an answer.