# Defining Wick/normal ordering beyond rearranging the order of annihilation and creation operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, vacuum, wick-theorem

Most introductory quantum field theory books define Wick ordering as rearranging a product of creation and annihilation operators such that all the creation operators appear to the left of any annihilation operators. I understand why this is useful.

In some books they hint at something deeper going on, including the subtraction of an infinite constant. What exactly is going on here? What is being subtracted and does this have any physical implications?

Comment: Can you quote or provide a reference?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133426/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10804/2451 and links therein.